# How to make parentheses bigger (to fit the size of an expression inide of them) in an R plot label?

Tags: r

For example. Consider the code

```
plot(rnorm(10), xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
mtext(side=1, expression( paste("Log"["10"], ( frac( "x","y") ) )))
```

I would like to make the parentheses in the expression larger, to fit the size of the expression inside them. Note the expression is actually much more complicated in my actual script, but this is a minimal reproducible example that captures the essence of the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at `demo(plotmath)`.

Comment: @Pascal thanks for pointing out the demo, the grouping options get buried in the help file, would have never noticed them because it doesn't explain what "grouping" is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the demo pointed out by @Pascal, the answer is to use `bgroup`

```
mtext(side=1, expression( paste("Log"["10"], bgroup("(", frac( "x","y"), ")" ) )))
```